# How to get the graph site ID of the current using V2.0 REST Endpoint?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, graph

I'd like to perform some operations that are only available using the GRAPH Api (adding content from the content type hub for example).

But I'm in a context where I can only perform operations using the SharePoint authenticated context (Power Automate SharePoint connector if it matters). That's why I need to use the SharePoint REST V2 endpoint (`/_api/v2.0`) and not the standard graph endpoint.

I'm struggling to get the current site ID (graph ID, not SharePoint ID).

How can I retrieve it ?

There are attributes on File object that provide DriveID (VroomDriveID), but I did not find similar attribute for site or web.

I tried:

- get `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/v2.0/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite` but it does not work
- get the drive ID first, then trying to reach the drive:

  1. `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/getlist('/sites/mysite/sitepages')/items?$expand=File&$filter=FSObjType eq 0&$top=1&$select=File/VroomItemID,File/VroomDriveID` (assuming there's at least one page in the site). This allow me to retrieve one DriveID
  2. then `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/2.0/drives/<<value of VroomDriveID>>`. It also fails
- *search* for the current site : `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/v2.0/sites?search='/sites/mysite'`. The query does not fails, but return an empty array

Comment: Which power automate action are you using?

Comment: I'm using the SharePoint HTTP action to benefits the SharePoint connection (easier that HTTP with AAD auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt is almost right! It's `$search`not `search`.

This URL should return the **Graph Site ID**:

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/v2.0/sites?$search=*
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/v2.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2023-09-30T05:41:06Z",
            "id": "yourtenant.sharepoint.com,guid1,guid2",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-09-30T05:46:49Z",
            "name": "yoursite",
            "webUrl": "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite",
            "root": {},
            "sensitivityLabel": {},
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostName": "yourtenant.sharepoint.com"
            },
            "title": "your site name"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you try the same request at the tenant level, you will get all sites your user can access. My response has only one site as the request includes the `/sites/yoursite` path in the URL.

As you mentioned the **Power Automate SharePoint connector**, did you know that you can use the **Office 365 Groups connector** to send HTTP requests to SharePoint (`/sites` endpoint). It's a standard connector. It's a great workaround to get data from SharePoint with Graph API and not REST API!

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. But the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) isn't accurate (no `$` sign). Or is there any syntax diff between graph.microsoft.com and v2.0 endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

Several possibles answers

1. [jleture's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/309620/3497), which is quite simple
2. The graph ID format is `<hostname>,<guid of site>,<guid of web>`, so it can actually be computed if you have the sharepoint IDs
3. You can get a "graph" site using the sharepoint ID. For example, to add a content type to a list from the CThub : `/_api/v2.0/sites/664097d8-07f2-4b06-9107-604eea39ee55/lists/db411124-720f-48a9-7fbc-73d2704fb352/contentTypes/addCopyFromContentTypeHub`, even thought it's under the v2.0 endpoint